# Hybris create custom selector in platform init page + create/not create user during system init

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

System setup (create custom selector in platform init page, with "create DemoUser" and "not create DemoUser" options). Depending on the value selected, create or not create DemoUser user during system init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find **CoreSystemSetup** class in your core extension to hook ServiceLayer code into the Hybris initialization and update life-cycle events. If you don't have, create the one.

Now, inside SystemSetup class, you need to define a method using **@SystemSetupParameterMethod**

Like

```
@SystemSetupParameterMethod
public List<SystemSetupParameter> getSystemSetupParameters()
{
    final List<SystemSetupParameter> params = new ArrayList<SystemSetupParameter>();

    final SystemSetupParameter customDataParameter = new SystemSetupParameter("createDemoUser");
    customDataParameter.setLabel("Create demo Users?");
    customDataParameter.addValue("true");
    customDataParameter.addValue("false", true);
    params.add(customDataParameter);

    return params;
}
```

Now you can fetch user selected value inside createProjectData(`@SystemSetup(type = Type.PROJECT, process = Process.ALL)`)

Like

```
@SystemSetup(type = Type.PROJECT, process = Process.ALL)
public void createProjectData(final SystemSetupContext context) throws Exception
{
    LOG.info("-----> createCustomData : " + context.getParameter(CoreConstants.EXTENSIONNAME + 
        "_createDemoUser"));
}
```

---

For more details, refer [Hooks-for-Initialization-and-Update-Process](https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/8bcb3edb86691014af58b7162c06e1d5.html)

Comment: interesting functionality, thanks a lot! could u help me out with another task, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52153714/hybris-hide-attribute-in-backoffice. as I see it right now, I need to impose SearchRestrictions for all User groups.

Comment: I'm glad it helps you!! your question seems deleted

Comment: yes. I created a new one for that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52169569/how-do-i-restrict-insert-in-hybris?noredirect=1#comment91304717_52169569

Comment: @Down Voter - Spend some time to comment (why the downvote?), so I can improve what you found wrong.