# How do I restrict insert in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Like I know, I can use SearchRestrictions to restrict get operations. But what about insert_update? For instance, I want to remove an opportunity to insert Products with CHECK approvalStatus.

Comment: I know, you have asked a related question and later deleted. It seems you do not want "CHECK" status at all. Am I right?

Comment: yep, that's true.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a question that is answerable?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions so you will be better prepared and able to ask a question that will be well received and more importantly **answerable**. This is not a *send me teh codez* site, that is now how this site works.

Comment: and stop reposting [down voted deleted questions as duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52153714/hybris-hide-attribute-in-backoffice-in-java-in-servicelayer) doing so is abuse of the system and will be reported and get you question banned by the system.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome that question was asked in a wrong way, so I rewrote it. I'll read the guide.

Answer (score -1):

Search restrictions don't work like that. They restrict queries that are made against the database. How? The condition you add to a search restriction is added to the where clause of the select statement of the query. An INSERT query does not have a where clause. At least not those, that are generated when using impex.

Also impex is not the right tool for your purpose. Impex should only be used to import flawless data. It is just a simpler way of inserting data into a database, just like an insert statement in sql. You don't want data in an impex file that needs further checks.

Just filter those lines, that have undesired values. Then you can import the rest.